# Binary Search Return Error

Tags: c

This code works, except returning false in the end. Why does not it return false appropriately?

I know it is the case, because the code is part of a greater program and supposed to say "the needle isn't found" when returning false. However, I don't see that message.

```
/**
 * Returns true if value is in array of n values, else false.
 */
int lower = 0;

bool search(int value, int values[], int n) {
    int higher = n;

    if (n < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    while (lower <= higher) {
        int middle = (lower + higher) / 2;
        if (values[middle] == value) {
            return true;
        } else if (values[middle] < value) {
            lower = middle + 1;
        } else if (values[middle] > value) {
            lower = middle - 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the contents of `values`? It *is* sorted? What is the values of `value` and `n`? Have you tried stepping through the code line by line in a debugger? And why is `lower` a global variable?

Comment: I'm no Jon Skeet, but it seems to me that you are never rebalancing your `higher` value, but instead only move around `lower`.  Have you stepped through this code to see what it is actually doing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: That looks like the answer to me.

Comment: It's too bad it's such a poorly presented question.

Comment: Guys, the code works fine in that it finds the value. It just does not return false, when it is supposed to. That is the problem

Comment: @ArdaBoğa Regarding where you define (and more importantly *initialize*) the variable `lower`, think about what would happen if you call your function twice, first with a large array and then with a smaller array. That could lead to `lower` being out of bounds in the second call and give you undefined behavior as it may place `middle` out of bounds too.

Comment: @ArdaBoga: have you tried searching for the lowest value?

Answer (score 2):

You have a logic error.

```
  else if(values[middle]>value)
  {
     lower=middle-1;
  }
```

should be:

```
  else if(values[middle]>value)
  {
     higher=middle-1;
  }
```

Better still, you can just use:

```
  else
  {
     higher=middle-1;
  }
```

Since the `if` and `else-if` before that take care of the other two cases.